# Ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app' в Pycharm (python - fastapi)

Tags: python, pycharm, fastapi, python-import

Структура проекта

```
fastapi_project
├── app (python package)/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api  (python package)/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── endpiont.py
│   ├── schemas  (python package)/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
```

endpiont.py

```
from app import schemas
```

Ошибка:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Ну похоже что вы endpoint.py напрямую вызываете. Нужно наоборот общий пакет запускать, который все вложенное будет запускать.

Comment: запускается через main.py

Comment: если писать просто import schemas, то работает 
но для миграции алембика и pytest нужно именно from app import schemas

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы общий пакет `app` был доступен для импорта во вложенных модулях, нужно запускать `main` как модуль пакета `app`, а не как отдельный скрипт.

Через командную строку запускать нужно так:

```
python -m app.main
```

Для запуска через PyCharm - в настройках запуска меняете "script" на "module" (запуск как модуля, соответствует `-m` в командной строке), и правее указываете имя `app.main`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]