# Ошибка импорта, попытка относительного импорта с неизвестным родительским пакетом

Tags: python, импорт

[image: gj]

У меня следующая структура проекта, в файле "main.py" я создаю экземпляр класса который находится в другой папке и был импортирован в "main.py" при помощи `from ...Poker.Game.class_Game import Game`, но при попытке запустить "main.py" выбрасывает ошибку

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

что делать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите как и откуда вы запускаете `main.py`

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1550294/1365

Answer (score 1):

В целом, относительный импорт работает только когда вы запускаете код не как отдельный скрипт (условно, `python main.py`), а как модуль из пакета (`python -m package.main`). Судя по ошибке, вы запускаете именно как отдельный скрипт.

Чтобы было доступно для импорта все, что есть в пакете `Pocker`, через его имя (абсолютный импорт) или через точки (относительный внутри этого пакета), то нужно запускать не как отдельный скрипт main.py, а из внешней директории, где лежит Pocker, через `python -m Pocker.Game.main`.

Импорт вместо `from ...Poker.Game.class_Game import Game` делать как `from Poker.Game.class_Game import Game` (абсолютный импорт) или `from .class_Game import Game` (относительный). Какой-то сложный относительный импорт тут не нужен, т.к. `main.py` и `class_Game.py` находятся в одном и том же пакете.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по скриншоту, вы находитесь в одной папке, и весь путь прописывать не надо:

```
from .class_Game import Game
```